# Is this a permissible way of proving/showing this statement?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, proof-writing, solution-verification

The task is to show that $$\sin\phi=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}) $$

with an emphasis on **show**. The task does not specifically state, **prove** this statement.

So, what I did, is to transform the **right side** until I got what is stated on the **left side**. $$ \sin\phi=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}) = ... = ...=\sin\phi  $$

Was this a valid way to show the given statement, or should I have transformed the **left side** until I get the statement on the **right side**, like this: $$ \sin\phi=...=...=\frac{1}{2i}(e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}) $$

Or, is there perhaps even no difference, and I can choose either way?

I am sorry for this seemingly trivial question, as I am still a Calc 1 newbie and would love to know the difference between showing and actually proving a statement. Because it seems to me like the first way is merely showing what is given, thus not a full proof, while the nature of the second one, namely taking the left side as the springboard and transforming it until we have what was to be shown, looks more reasonable. Maybe I'm also just overthinking. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I 'd say there is no difference. I beleive that proving the equality of two things is always valid both ways even if only proved one way unless you've added other solutions along the way that could be influencing your proof, eg by squaring both sides.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you have a complicated definition $F(\phi)$ of $\sin\phi$ in terms of simpler things defined before, and in the same way you have a complicated definition $G(\phi)$ of $e^{i\phi}$ in terms of simpler things defined before. You are told to prove
$$F(\phi)=G(\phi)\qquad\forall\,\phi\ ,$$
using the facts valid in the "simpler" world. As "$=$" is a symmetric relation such a proof can go in the direction
$$F(\phi)= \ldots =\quad\ldots\quad=\ldots=G(\phi)$$
as well as in the direction
$$G(\phi)= \ldots =\quad\ldots\quad=\ldots=F(\phi)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks, Mr.Blatter! I'll keep that in mind and think back to it always :-) Oder, wie sagt man so schön, Dankesehr!

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{i\phi}=\cos \phi +i \sin \phi,~~ e^{-i\phi}=\cos \phi -i\sin \phi$$
add these two to get $$\sin \phi= \frac{e^{i\phi}-e^{-i\phi}}{2i}$$

Comment: thanks, but I already have the solution. My question was which way of proving would be permissible.